# requirejs: Why does a function defined in a module not have access to local variables inside require() and how can i achieve this?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

This is my first tinker with requirejs and i think i have a good handle on it with the exception of: **Why does a function defined in a module not have access to local variables inside require() and how can i achieve this?**

It would be greatly appreciated if we could focus on the question and **NOT** the fact that i used eval(), better or alternate ways to define test(), or a typo that may exist in the code below.

Given the following code in global namespace:

```
require(["test"], function(testModule) {
    var test1 = testModule.test1;// same as local test()
    var test2 = testModule.test2; // modified to work as module

    //local function same as testModule.test1
    function test (name, test){
        return test+'='+eval(name+test);
    }

    //define class & instance for testing
    var MyClass1 = function (name) {
        this.name = name;
    };
    var mc1 = new MyClass1('instance 1');
    var objName = 'mc1'

    test(objName, '.name');   // works as expected
    test1(objName, '.name');  // error: mc1 is not defined
    test1.call(this, objName, '.name');  // error: mc1 is not defined
    test2(mc1, objName+'.name');  // works as expected

})
```

and the test module definition:

```
define({
    test1: function (name, test){
        return test+'='+eval(name+test);
    },

    test2: function (obj, test){
        var parts = test.split('.');
        parts[0] = 'obj';
        test = parts.join('.');
        return test+'='+eval(test);
    }
});
```

**The question:**

**part a)** When i call test1(objName, '.name'), why does it not see the local variable defined as var mc1 = new MyClass1('instance 1')?

I understand that this is for GOOD reason having to do with keeping the global namespace clean, i just don't understand how it can't see it.  define()'s this points to the same namespace as require()'s this.

**part b)** If i wanted to give the test module access to var mc1 how could i go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i call test1(objName, '.name'), why does it not see the local variable defined as var mc1 = new MyClass1('instance 1')?

They are defined in different functions. It's the same reason why this won't work:

```
function a() {
   var hello = 'world'
   b()
}

function b() {
   alert(hello)
}
```

---

> If i wanted to give the test module access to var mc1 how could i go about doing so?

Change definition to:

```
test1: function (name, test, mc1){ ... }
```

And pass mc1 variable explicitly:

```
test1(objName, '.name', mc1)
```

This has nothing to do with require.js, it's how javascript works.

Comment: GOT it and thanks for the clarity.  I was under the impression that function a was the global name space.

Answer (score 1):

If we disregard the fact that the following code pollutes the global namesapce, what you are doing is functionally equivalent to this:

```
// This is the callback you passed to `require`. I've added a
// name to it.
function foo(testModule) {
    var test1 = testModule.test1;// same as local test()
    var test2 = testModule.test2; // modified to work as module

    // ... etc... its all the same as your original code.

    var mc1 = new MyClass1('instance 1');

    // ... etc ...
}

// This is the module `test` that your `require` call was loading.
var test = {
    test1: function (name, test){
        return test+'='+eval(name+test);
    },

    test2: function (obj, test){
        var parts = test.split('.');
        parts[0] = 'obj';
        test = parts.join('.');
        return test+'='+eval(test);
    }
};

// This is what happens when RequireJS executes your module.
foo(test);
```

The way I've reorganized it above should make it clear why you can't
access anything inside the function's closure.

As to how to do what you want to do, you could just pass object references to your functions. Or if you need to provide access to multiple objects at once, or want to change what an symbol refers to, you could pass a namespace:

```
var ns = {
   mc1:  new MyClass1('instance 1'),
   mc2:  new MyClass1('instance 2'),
   // ...
};

test(ns, "mc1", ...);
```

Doing it this way, `test` could assign a new value to `mc1` if needed:

```
function test(ns, name, ...) {
    ns[name] = new MyClass1(...);
}
```